# How come my useState isnt working for my gatsby site?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  const metaData = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              name
            }
            html
          }
        }
      }
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
          locations
          profileIntroduction
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const [reviewsArray] = useState(
    metaData.allMarkdownRemark.edges
  )

  const [currentReviewIndex, setCurrentReviewIndex] = useState(0)

  const [currentReview] = useState(
    reviewsArray[currentReviewIndex]
  )

  const increaseCurrentReview = () => {
    setCurrentReviewIndex(1)
  }

  return (
    <div>
        <Layout>
          <div 
          className='hero-image'
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${heroImage1})`
          }}>
            <div className='home-hero-image-dark-cover'>
              <div className='home-hero-image-header'>
                {metaData.site.siteMetadata.title}
              </div>
              <div className='home-hero-image-header sub'>
                {metaData.site.siteMetadata.locations}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='about-section'>
            <div className='about-section-image about-section-item'>
            </div>
            <div className='about-section-text about-section-item'>
              <div className='about-section-header'>
                {metaData.site.siteMetadata.title}
              </div>
              <p>
                {metaData.site.siteMetadata.profileIntroduction}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='client-testimonials-section'>
            <div className='client-testimonials-section-dark-cover'>
              <button id='left-arrow' className='left-arrow arrow'>
                {'<'}
              </button>
              <div>
                <div className='client-testimonials-section-header'>
                  Client Testimonials
                </div>
                <div 
                className='client-testimonials-section-header review'
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: currentReview.node.html}}
                >
                </div>
                <div className='client-testimonials-section-header review'>
                  - {currentReview.node.frontmatter.name}
                </div>
              </div>
              <button id='right-arrow' 
              className='right-arrow arrow' 
              onClick={increaseCurrentReview}>
                {'>'}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

If it makes a difference, I also have a bug in the console: React-Hot-Loader: react--dom patch is not detected. React 16.6+ features may not work. Otherwise I have no idea why useState isnt working here. Granted I'm not too familiar with the usestate hooks of react, but everything seems to be on the up and up.

Comment: Isn't metaData an asynchronous result?

Comment: Yes, but my state is receiving the metadata results properly, its when I try to call increaseCurrentReviewIndex and call the state changer for currentReviewIndex that it doesn't work. That's the main problem I'm looking for a solution to... I wasn't clear enough in the question to my detriment

Comment: `when I try to call increaseCurrentReviewIndex` The code in your question never calls increaseCurrentReviewIndex

Comment: Is it not calling it, or is it setCurrentReviewIndex that's not working, because I tried adding a console.log to increaseCurrentReview, and the console.log is going through, but not the setCurrentReviewIndex that is supposed to change the state.

Comment: Other than one of the initial values for another `useState` hook, no code in your question consumes `currentReviewIndex` after it's updated, so I wouldn't expect much to happen after setting it to `1`. You can drop a `useEffect(() => console.log(currentReviewIndex), [currentReviewIndex]);` in the body to test that state is being updated or not very easily.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you write `setCurrentReviewIndex(1)`?